# Batch file that opens a URL and press CTRL+A in the focused browser

Tags: batch-file, url, keypress

I have this base code for a .bat that opens Firefox browser with an URL for 600 seconds and when the time runs out, it loops infinitly. What i want is that with this code, every time it opens the URL right after, the batch simulate pressing CTRL+A in the Firefox browser, that's all

```
    :loop 
    cls
    taskkill /F /IM Firefox.exe
    cls
    taskkill /F /IM crashreporter.exe
    cls
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -private-window http://google.com
    TIMEOUT /T 600
    GOTO loop
```

I want the .bat to enter the URL and press CTRL+A in the browser right after that.

Comment: `powershell "(new-object -COM Wscript.Shell).SendKeys('^a')"`

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript. Please only use relevant tags

Comment: Where to place it?                                                                                  powershell "(new-object -COM Wscript.Shell).SendKeys('^a')"

Comment: Why so many `cls`? Just use `echo off` or do `@taskkill...`